# Setting up JMS integration test config in Maven2

Tags: maven-2, integration-testing

In a project I have put together, I need set up some JMS queues in order to run my integration tests.

Where is best to store my scripts to set the environment up?

I have a parent project, and typical modules like EAR and WAR modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely your JMS queues are defined in the application's EAR file.  If so, the EAR module would be the best place to store the creation scripts for testing.  Now exactly where to store them in the module (or project if you so choose) is really up to you.  But the folks over at Apache Maven do give some guidelines for standard directory layout [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

According to that page and the fact that this is for testing, the best place should be src/test/resources.